# Android SQLite Delete Row From Table Where 2 Arguments

Tags: android, sqlite, row, where-clause

This is my database :

```
// the names for database columns
    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "vremena";
    public final static String TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public final static String TABLE_COLUMN_ONE = "dan";
    public final static String TABLE_COLUMN_TWO = "vrijeme";
```

I'm trying to create a method which takes 2 arguments and deletes a selected row from the database :

```
public void delete(String dan, int vrijeme){
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLUMN_ONE+"="+dan, TABLE_COLUMN_TWO+"="+vrijeme);
    }
```

Am getting this error :

```
The method delete(String, String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)
```

I know I'm doing something wrong within delete method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have a look at the API Docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

```
delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
Convenience method for deleting rows in the database.
```

You should do this:

```
public void delete(String dan, int vrijeme){
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, 
            TABLE_COLUMN_ONE + " = ? AND " + TABLE_COLUMN_TWO + " = ?", 
            new String[] {dan, vrijeme+""});
}
```